# "negative logarithm of the survivor function of the residuals"

Tags: r, math, statistics

for my thesis I have to plot the negative logarithm of the survivor function of the residuals of my model against [image: e_1(gamma(1]

where e_i are the residuals resulted from my model small gamma is an estimated value also resulting from a weibull distribution and the capital gamma is devoted to the gamma function.

Basically I have to recreate the following picture with my own results:

[image]

The problem is I don't know what S looks like, and how to compute it nor did I found anything about "survivor function" on the web. I took a look at the original literature (Engle and Russel 1998) and they call it "survival function". Well the survival function is defined as one minus the cumulative distribution of the residuals. So at this point I thought that with command in R CDF I may be able to calculate the cumulative distribution of the residuals. But my Rstudio does not find the CDF. Another approach is with ecdf but it does not return the values it return a function.
My question is does anyone know, how to calculate "negative logarithm of the survival function of the residuals" in R?

My thx

Comment: well I confused, is the survival function not the same as survivor function?

Comment: according to my literature the hazard function is defined as:"hazard function given by the probability density of e divided by the survival function of s which is simply one minus the cumulative distribution function."

Comment: @RuiBarradas um, "The survivor function is the hazard function" is not a poor explanation, it is actually just incorrect.

Comment: Mark, I think you need to go back to the origin of the diagram and see how they defined "survivor function". People trying to help here are probably going to assume the context is survival or reliability, both of which are so-called time to event models, in which the quantity of interest is lifetime, that is, time from a beginning until death or failure. I don't see how that fits stocks, but maybe the author of the original diagram has an explanation about it.

Comment: Hi Robert,  my second comment is a quote from the originally literature Engle and Russel (1998) regarding survival function